# Sort products by most viewed

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I'm using a plugin that already count product views and store it in a table called 'mwb_wpr_data'.

The query to list the product views is:

`SELECT DISTINCT('productid') FROM 'mwb_wpr_data' WHERE 'action' = 'view'`

The productid field is a FK to Woocomerce products.

How can I modify the Woocommerce default sorting, so it will display products by order of most views based in the table 'mwb_wpr_data'?

Current code using the plugin Post View Counter:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_view_filter' );
function my_view_filter($query){
    if ( 
        $query->is_main_query() && 
        ( $query->is_home() || $query->is_archive() || $query->is_search() )
    ) {
            $query->set('suppress_filters', 'false');
            $query->set('orderby', 'post_views');
            $query->set('order', 'DESC');
    }
}
```

Comment: your product views should have been saved using post meta. It will be easier.

Comment: Your product views should store as a product meta it will easy to sort using sort by meta value

Comment: can you share that plugin name wiith me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to showing the the products which was most viewed , so you can follow these below steps .

Steps :1 I have add menu in admin panel using (add_menu_page) function. in function file

```
function admin_manage_users22(){
add_menu_page('My Page Title', 'MVP', 'manage_options', 'MVP_backend_view', 
'MVP_backend_view' );
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'admin_manage_users22');
```

Step :2 Get product details after user view product it's +1 counter value in wp_postmeta with post id. default value set 1

```
function MVP_product_details($product ) {

$post_id = get_the_ID();
$count_key = 'AK_product_view_count';
$count     = get_post_meta( $post_id, $count_key, true );
if ( empty( $count ) ) {
    delete_post_meta( $post_id, $count_key );
    update_post_meta( $post_id, $count_key, '1' );
    echo "count null"; 
}else{
    $count ++;
    update_post_meta( $post_id, $count_key, (string) $count );
}
}
 add_filter( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_args', 'MVP_product_details', 10, 2 );
```

Step :3 Now you can get most viewed product details simply using below code.

```
function MVP_backend_view(){
$count_key                = 'AK_product_view_count';
$query_args               = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 3,
    'no_found_rows'  => 1,
    'post_status'    => 'publish',
    'post_type'      => 'product',
    'orderby'        => 'meta_value',
    'order'          => 'DESC',
    'meta_key'       => $count_key,
);
$query_args['meta_query'] = array(
    array(
        'key'     => $count_key,
        'value'   => '0',
        'type'    => 'numeric',
        'compare' => '>',
    ),
);
$zwcmvp_query = new WP_Query( $query_args );
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about the plugin you're using (it would be great if you give additional info about it) but I've been using [Post Views Counter](https://wordpress.org/plugins/post-views-counter/) for years and it works really well.

It even has a query parameter for **WP_Query** (to query posts by post views):

**EDIT:** This query parameter won't work without the [Post Views Counter](https://wordpress.org/plugins/post-views-counter/) plugin as it's not a WordPress default parameter.

More info about this plugin API here: 
https://dfactory.eu/docs/post-views-counter/developers-api/

```
$query_args = array(
    'posts_per_page'   => 12,
    'order'            => 'DESC',
    'suppress_filters' => false,  //required param
    'orderby'          => 'post_views',  //required param
);
$query      = new WP_Query( $query_args );

if ( $query->have_posts() ):
    while ( $query->have_posts() ): $query->the_post();

//Post content here
    echo get_the_title();

    endwhile;
endif;
```

I hope this helps,
Cheers!

Comment: Would you be able to help me using it with  'pre_get_posts'? Would it be possible? I have updated my question with the code!

Comment: here are the possible values of [`orderby`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters) and `'post_views'` is not one of them.

Comment: @Reigel is correct. orderby does not accept the value "post_views", mainly as this data is not recorded by Wordpress as default.

Comment: Hello @Reigel, you're right it's not WordPress default you'll need to add the plugin first. I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: @BernardoLima, I never tried this using pre_get_posts, why are you using it anyway? If you're working on a custom template, change the query directly. If you do not, try implementing a child theme and update the code directly (it will automatically override it) < https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes > . Let me know to give you additional help.

Comment: even with or without plugins, `'post_views'` is not a valid `order_by` value.

Comment: @Reigel if you're curious, ask them how they did it: https://dfactory.eu/docs/post-views-counter/developers-api/

Comment: @Reigel after looking at the plugin I can confirm that  they are indeed registering it as an orderby parameter

**public function extend_pre_query( $query ) {
  if ( isset( $query->query_vars['orderby'] ) && $query->query_vars['orderby'] === 'post_views' )
   $query->pvc_orderby = true;
 }**

Answer (score 1):

According to me you have set the correct pre_get_post but problem is in your if condition.

You have set the current_user_can which not correct filter is for every user so if you are not login in with administrator role than your query will not work.

```
current_user_can('administrator')
```

Remove this above one from the condition.

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_view_filter' );
function my_view_filter($query){
    if ($query->is_main_query() && ( $query->is_home() || $query->is_archive() || $query->is_search() )
    ) {
            $query->set('suppress_filters', 'false');
            $query->set('orderby', 'post_views');
            $query->set('order', 'DESC');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I was logged in as administrator and could see those changes :(

Comment: I don't know where post_views columns is located at, I've found this code in the web, people said that this code could be used with the plugin "Post Views Counter"

Comment: ohh god.. You need to check that first if it is in the post meta than it can be achieve by different query. check your plugins directory. Is there any folder related to products view? if yes than give us the name

Comment: I have a table called 'post_views', would that count for something?

Comment: It dosn't work!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so the RIGHT way to do this would be

1. Change how your post view counts are stored, so that they are stored as postmeta of each product (post) in a field like _post_views_count.
2. Use meta_key & orderby in wp_query like this

   ```
   $args = array(
       'meta_key' => '_post_views_count',
       'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
       'order' => 'ASC'
   );
   ```

< EDIT >

IF you want to use the same plugin for recording your product views, I'd set up a function that fires every time a post view is added to the table that updates a postmeta field of the product.

Is it elegant? No.

Will it work? Yes.

Answer (score 1):

According to the plugins documentation you are required to pass the post_type as well in order for this to work, i.e.

```
$args = array(
    'order' => 'asc',
    'post_type' => 'event',
    // required by PVC
    'suppress_filters' => false,
    'orderby' => 'post_views',
    'fields' => ''
);
$most_viewed = get_posts( $args );
```

That code is in the post that @Marounm linked to in comment higher up.

Try passing the post_type arg as well i.e.

```
 $query->set('post_type', 'product');
```