# Sort Woocommerce products by most viewed using Post View Counter

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Any ideas would be much appreciated.

I am trying to reorder my woocommerce products by most viewed using the [post-views-counter plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/post-views-counter/).

Followed these examples which did not seem to work [Sort products by most viewed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50518802/sort-products-by-most-viewed)

```
function my_view_filter($query){
  if ($query->is_main_query() && ( $query->is_home() || $query- >is_archive() 
   )
     ) {
     $query->set('post_type', 'product');
     $query->set('suppress_filters', false);
     $query->set('orderby', 'post_views');
     $query->set('order', 'asc');
     $query->set('fields', '');
     }
   }
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_view_filter' );
```

Comment: Order them where exactly, on the dashboard, on the shop page..etc?

Comment: On the shop pages

Answer (score 4):

First of all, the plugin you're trying to use is outdated. Secondly, it seems to create a table to hold the views and this would require changing the actual MySQL query to retrieve posts ordered by date which is a lot of work looking what you need to do.

You could simply just save views on visit to post meta and use that to order products on the catalog like this:

```
/**
 * Setting post count on each visit
 *
 */
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product', 'prefix_save_product_views' );
function prefix_save_product_views(  ) {

    $product_id = get_the_ID();
    $increment = 1;
    $current_visit_count = get_post_meta( $product_id, 'product_visit_count', true );

    $total_visit_count = (int)$current_visit_count + $increment;
    update_post_meta( $product_id, 'product_visit_count', $total_visit_count );

}

/**
 * Change the display order based on visit count only in Catalog
 *
 */
add_filter('woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args', 'prefix_woocommerce_catalog_orderby');
function prefix_woocommerce_catalog_orderby( $args ) {
    $args['meta_key'] = 'product_visit_count';
    $args['orderby'] = 'meta_value_num';
    $args['order'] = 'desc';
    return $args;
}
```

You'd run into multiple issues using `pre_get_posts`

Comment: Thanks  but this snippet seems to break my site

Comment: Where are you adding it?

Comment: in functions.php

Comment: I've added the same code to my functions file and it didn't produce any error, please make sure there isn't something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Remove product category/tag meta from its original position
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_meta', 40 );
// Add product meta in new position
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_meta', 5 );
```